# How to aggregate complex web pages

Tags: django, web, web-frameworks

What is the common approach/design pattern to build a web page with provides multiple group of possibly unrelated data. Eg. facebook - there are multiple sections in these pages like my friends list, my wall, ads... all these must be fetched and formatted separately. How to aggregate these contents. I can design things as a single page template, but would like to know which is the best approach to be used these scenarios. (I am using django,python and JS)

thanks,
Den

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two commonly used approaches. One is you can create [custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/), and the other is to use [template context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors).

Either way, these allow you to put data that is common to all pages into say a common base template. Your other site pages use [template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance) from the base template to get that extra content.

I find myself writing a lot of custom inclusion tags, but I know others prefer context processors.

Answer (score 0):

i would create many files, one for each part of your page. Then i would include these in my "big page" which would make them being rendered every time a page that includes these files is loaded, or have I understood you wrong ?